# Configuration in Adobe Flex Builder

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, builder

I installed Adobe FlexBuilder 3 Pro Eclipse Plug-in 3.0.2, but when i want to configure weblogic inside widows->preferences->server then server link button won't be appeared inside flex builder. can anyone help me out how i have to configure weblogic inside adobe flex builder.

Answer (score 0):

The Flex Perspective is not configured to show the 'Server' view by default. I do not know how to make it permanent but to see the server view. Select Windows --> Show View --> Others --> Server --> Servers.

Answer (score 0):

May be **WTP plugin** not function correctly or Missing,

but for **weblogic and it's portal** there are Oracle provides bundle eclipse which is very helpful in development so,

I suggest you should **Download**  [Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse 11g](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/oepe-11g-090965.html) and to *integrate*  **FlexBuilder3** in it Copy **link folder** from *root* of **FlexBuider3** to OPEC eclipse root, or

Other integration option is download FlexBuilder3/FlashBuilder Plugin From Adobe Site

that how you can easly use Oracle Weblogic + Portal+ Adobe FlexBuilder/Flashbuilder

**Note:***You may need to Update Flex Builder from option provider in Help menu of Eclipse*

Hope that help